# FileNotFoundError in custon docker python image

Tags: python, docker

I have a python code in which I am opening a file and then extracting a particular data. Below is that code:

```
def get_mode(first, last):
    with open('/srv/config/mode.conf','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(first):
                try:
                    start = line.index(first) + len(first)
                    end = line.index(last, start)
                    return line[start:end]
                except ValueError:
                    return "Default Mode"
```

This works fine when I execute the python code. But I want to run it as a docker so I have converted it into docker image using below command:

```
sudo docker build -t mydocker .
```

Above command successfully convert the python code into docker image. Then I run the image using

```
sudo docker run -it mydocker
```

but it gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_script.py", line 68, in <module>
   main()
  File "./my_script.py", line 52, in main
    mode = get_mode("user "," :")
  File "./my_script.py", line 15, in get_publish_string
    with open('/srv/config/mode.conf','r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/srv/config/mode.conf'
```

How is that possible that if the python code is running fine then why docker image is giving error.

CONTENT OF DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3

ADD my_script.py /

ADD mode.conf /srv/config

RUN pip3 install psutil

CMD [ "python3", "./my_script.py" ]
```

Comment: Please post contents of the Dockerfile. You need to add the config file inside your docker container or otherwise mount it. It won't be automagically available :)

Comment: @favoretti I have added the content of Dockerfile. Can you please tell me how to mention that config file inside the Dockerfile. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the config file to your image as well.

```
RUN mkdir -p /srv/config
ADD mode.conf /srv/config
```

or something like that.

Comment: It gives error `ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder771094008/mode.conf: no such file or directory`

Comment: I have updated my question with the content of Dockerfile

Comment: Is your mode.conf in the same directory as your dockerfile?  I also modified my answer to include mkdir just in case the directory does not exist

Comment: No. mode.conf is in `/srv/config/`. It is not in the same directory. Do I also need to copy it to the my current directory where Dockerfile is present. Also if I include `RUN mkdir -p /srv/config` I think it will create a directory but the directory is already present.

Comment: Then add path to your ADD /srv/config/mode.conf /srv/config. If path already exists on your image, then you do not need mkdir but it does not hurt either.

Comment: I have included this line now `ADD /srv/config/mode.conf /srv/config` but still the same error.

Comment: Then try copying mode.conf to dockerfile directory, remove the path and run build again. It has been a while and it might not be able to add files from outside of the dockerfile directory. Actually this probably is the case.

Comment: yes. Copying the mode.conf to current directory resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you installed docker-compose by downloading a binary with curl, try removing it

```
rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose #replace the path with yours if it doesn't match
```

Then install docker-compose with apt

```
sudo apt install docker-compose
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

And try launching

```
docker-compose -v
```

to verify that everything is working well